# docker: command not found in linux

Tags: linux, docker, ssh

(Runs perfectly in local but not in ssh server) <-- this is the problem

I am using the linux shell on the Mac Book Pro. I do have docker desktop and I also used
`pip3 install docker`
which had been successfully installed.
(PS: And I am sure that the docker desktop was running when I tried to run the following command.)
But after I logged into my ssh server and I tried to run the command
`./name.sh` , it gave me the error  `line 9: docker: command not found in linux`

I have struggled on it for couple hours, plz help me.

Comment: I checked out bunch of the stack posts but none of them can solve my problem

Comment: what happens if you type `which docker`?

Comment: @klutt In ssh server? It shows nothing. In local, it shows /usr/local/bin/docker

Comment: And if you type `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @klutt In SSH server: /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:./:/snap/bin:/usr/bin:/pkg/bin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/altera9.1/quartus/bin:./:/opt/puppetlabs/bin

Comment: Wait. Have you installed docker on the ssh server?

Comment: @klutt This is what I am confused. I tried pip3 install docker in ssh --> it said I installed it successfully but when I tried to run the sh it doesn't work at all. Then I tried pip install, not working. Tried sudo install xxxx, it showed error. And I tried the solution on stackoverflow but it is still not working.

Comment: So just to be clear, you logged in on the ssh server, then ran `pip3 install docker` on that server?

Comment: @klutt yes, I did.

Comment: How about `ls -l /usr/local/bin/docker`?

Comment: @klutt It is in this file -- Requirement already satisfied: requests!=2.18.0,>=2.14.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from docker) (2.18.4)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you installed Docker Succesfully (To confirm that run "**docker --version**")

If it shows some version of docker then the error should be incorrect docker command

Comment: This command works perfectly and that's why I don't know where is the issue.

Comment: Then there may be a (spelling or other error)  in the bash script which you written... Try to cross check or review the code before you execute....

Comment: It was given by professor so I don't think there is a problem.